# Is there any module or built in feature for Mongo db version Document control using java

Tags: javascript, python, java, mongodb, spring-boot

For document versioning for Mongo db with Java , is there any collection or feature similar to ‘historical Collection’ module which is available for Python like given in  [historical-collection](https://pypi.org/project/historical-collection/)  ? Or similar to Mongoose versioned [mongoose-versioned](https://github.com/pier4all/mongoose-versioned)

Looking for any modules or built in feature for version control of a document to be used for Java- Mongodb

I have referred to the MongoDB Document Versioning Pattern blog, want to know if there is this feature built in with mongodb-java?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.